KafkaConsumer API Performance Challenges and Optimization Suggestions ( Kafka clients 3.6.1)
Scenario is: The user will give the offset as input and based on the offset we need to give 1000 messages from kafka topic and next offset.The kafka topic contains only one partition.
We are trying to migrate from old kafka to new kafka.In the old kafka we were using code like:
old code(kafka clients 0.8 .1):
FetchRequest req = new FetchRequestBuilder().clientId(clientName).addFetch(a_topic,
        a_partition, readOffset, fetchSize).build();
FetchResponse fetchResponse = consumer.fetch(req);
ByteBufferMessageSet set = fetchResponse.messageSet(a_topic, a_partition);

This code is super fast and same we are trying to achieve using KafkaConsumer API and getting slowness
New kafkaconsumer code is using(kafkaclients 3.6 .1)
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition("Test", 0);
consumer.seekToBeginning(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition));
long kafkaEarliestOffset = consumer.position(topicPartition);
try (KafkaConsumer < String, String > consumer = KafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(clientName, fetchSize)) {
    consumer.partitionsFor(topicName);
    consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition));
    consumer.seek(topicPartition, readOffset);
    do {
        ConsumerRecords < String, String > records =
            consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1500));
    } while (!end)

public static KafkaConsumer<String,String> createConsumer(String clientName,int fetchSize) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            String kafkaBrokerStr = Config.getConsumerPropValue("kafkabrokerslist");
            String groupId = Config.getConsumerPropValue("group.id");
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "");
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "1024");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,"500");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, "500");
            return new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(props);
   }

Code explanation:The assign, seek, finding earliestoffset and fetching records is taking time.
Poll Records Count: 500 diff: 1284 
Poll Records Count: 500 diff: 4

For the first 500 records it took 1284 ms and next 500 records it took 4 ms
why this much difference? I would like to improve the performance of first poll time?
How can I 1) how to fetch first 500 records in less time 2) efficiently do consumer.assign,consumer.seek and get the earliest offset in kafka?

Firstly, if you want speed, I'd think using C/C++, or maybe Go/Rust would be better option than Java. Secondly, why do you need to poll records at all if you're not processing them? And it's slow because you're using consumer groups, and it's not explained why

@OneCricketeer Thanks for your response. I am processing records and did not include that. modified the consumer group to empty and still it is slow.
The starting records taking time to fetch from kafka. For example if i give "0" as input offset and it is taking time as below (6 seconds)
Records Count :292 diff :1227
Records Count :296 diff :1234
If i give offset as 110999 and it is getting some fast.
Records Count :500 diff :1278
Records Count :500 diff :3

After applying all the steps and warming up consumer issue is not resolved
Why the starting records taking time


What type of hard drive are your brokers using? Seeking to early offsets on a spinning HDD will be slow, yes, as the data is brought back to page cache

@OneCricketeer Kafkahosts are with the configurations : 16 CPUs, 96 GB RAM..But with the old kafka brokers version ( 1.0) is running perfectly and fetching messages very fastly.This issue is coming only after upgrading kafka brokers(3.6.1)  and using kafkaconsumer API 3.6.1

I understood that from your post, but I was asking about the HDD not CPU/RAM. And like I said, your earlier code is not using consumer groups, so you're comparing two different things, as that increase in time includes network negotiations and leader discovery

@OneCricketeer My bad iam not using consumer groups.i have put as empty..i have modified the code..How to improve performace..please suggest some tips on this please..

The code shown is definitely using them. Group.id can not be empty (it may become randomly set if it is empty). Did you repost this under a different account? https://stackoverflow.com/q/79218718/2308683
