How to avoid delay in consuming Kafka messages using KafaConsumer API
I need to retrieve 1000 messages quickly from a Kafka topic, but the initial retrieval is slow kafka-clients 3.6.1 KafkaConsumer API.
We are migrating from an old Kafka client (version 0.8.1) to a newer Kafka client (version 3.6.1). The old Kafka implementation used the following approach, which was fast and efficient.
Observed issue:
Slowness in first poll: The first fetch of 500 records takes significantly longer (e.g., 1284 ms) compared to subsequent fetches (e.g., 4 ms).
Kafka consumer initialization: Operations like assign(), seek(), and fetching the earliest offset are taking time, and this impacts the performance.
Objective:
We need to reduce the time taken for the first poll (the first 500 records).
We are also looking for ways to efficiently perform assign(), seek(), and get the earliest offset in Kafka, without introducing unnecessary delays.
Please provide guidance on these areas to replicate the performance of the old Kafka implementation using the newer Kafka Consumer API.
For example if i give "0" as input offset and it is taking time as below (6 seconds)
Poll Records Count :292 diff :1227
Poll Records Count :292 diff :1181
Poll Records Count :296 diff :1234
Poll Records Count :292 diff :1133

If i give offset as 110999 and it is getting some fast.
Poll Records Count :500 diff :1278
Poll Records Count :500 diff :3


I am setting groupid to empty to avoid rebalancing and iam also warming up consumer, still the initial poll issue is not resolved
Why the starting records taking time. how to avoid this?

I need to collect 1000 records and give to the user as response. i am breaking out from loop after collecting 1000 records.
This is my updated properties and code:
List<JSONObject> msglist = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
try (KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer = KafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(clientName,fetchSize)){
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topicName, 0);
consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition));
Map<TopicPartition, Long> offsets = consumer.beginningOffsets(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition));
long kafkaEarliestOffset = offsets.get(topicPartition);
consumer.seek(topicPartition, readOffset);
consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(0));
do {    
ConsumerRecords < String, String > records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1500));
 for (ConsumerRecord< String, String > consumerRecord: records) {
 obj = new JSONObject(consumerRecord.value());
 msglist.add(obj);
 }
if (msglist.size() >= Math.round(limit/ inputReq.getApplicationArea().getReqInfo().size())
                    || (endTime - startTime) >= waitTime) {
end = true;
consumer.commitSync();
}
}while (!end);              
    `   
 props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "");
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,clientName);
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
            props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "1024");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,"500");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, "500");
            return new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(props);
`

I have tried with different Kafka consumer properties and still the slowness issue is not resolved. I am expecting the fastness of fetching records from Kafka topic using KafkaConsumer API.

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

public class OptimizedKafkaConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.setProperty("group.id", "consumer-group");
        props.setProperty("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.setProperty("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        props.setProperty("fetch.min.bytes", "50000");
        props.setProperty("fetch.max.wait.ms", "500");
        props.setProperty("max.poll.records", "1000");

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topic-name"));

        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                // Process messages in batches
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    System.out.printf("Consumed message: key = %s, value = %s%n", record.key(), record.value());
                }
                // Commit offsets asynchronously
                consumer.commitAsync();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    }
}


Thanks for your reply.In my case i cannot directly poll.User will give the input offset,based on this i need to  use consumer.assign and consumer.seek before polling the records.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
